# Html <img> tag navigation

Tags: javascript, html

How to transfer the control to a new page, when we click on particular image?

that is if we click on a particular image, the control must be tranfer to a new page(i./e HTML) page.

Comment: you can do some search before ask a question.

Comment: I recommend you to learn on this website: http://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

u just need to use image inside the anchor tag.have a look at the following code.

```
<a href="youradrres.html">
<img border="0" src="smiley.gif" alt="imageinfo" width="32" height="32"></a>
```

Comment: @Mallikarjun u can mark my answer as answered,if i answered ur question correctly :)

Answer (score 0):

add a image inside the anchor tag.

example:

```
<a href="page.html"><img src="your image path"></a>
```

but in firefox and IE, border will be shown around anchor tag that contains image. so use the following css property to remove that border:

```
a img
{
border:0;
}
```